# Output the DLL instead of .exe with cmake/mingw

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, mingw

I'm not very familiar with both cmake and mingw.

I have some source code that can be build with it (and the build process works fine with `mingw32-make`). The problem is, I would like to output the DLLs and not the .exe files.

I have some `CMakeList` file that I believe stores the configuration I have to change (that part should be responsible to produce the .exe files for .cpp files in `Examples/` directory, taking some dependencies into account):

```
# C examples
if(PSMOVE_BUILD_EXAMPLES)
    foreach(EXAMPLE example multiple dump_calibration battery_check)
        add_executable(${EXAMPLE} examples/c/${EXAMPLE}.c)
        target_link_libraries(${EXAMPLE} psmoveapi)
    endforeach()

    if(PSMOVE_BUILD_TRACKER AND PSMOVE_BUILD_TUIO_SERVER)
        include_directories(${PSMOVEAPI_SOURCE_DIR}/external/TUIO_CPP/TUIO)
        include_directories(${PSMOVEAPI_SOURCE_DIR}/external/TUIO_CPP/oscpack)
        add_executable(tuio_server examples/c/tuio_server.cpp
            external/TUIO_CPP/TUIO/TuioClient.cpp
...
            external/TUIO_CPP/oscpack/ip/win32/NetworkingUtils.cpp
            external/TUIO_CPP/oscpack/ip/win32/UdpSocket.cpp)
        set_target_properties(tuio_server PROPERTIES
            COMPILE_FLAGS -DOSC_HOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN)
        target_link_libraries(tuio_server psmoveapi psmoveapi_tracker)
    else()
        # Disable the TUIO Server if we don't build the tracker
        set(PSMOVE_BUILD_TUIO_SERVER OFF)
    endif()

    if(PSMOVE_BUILD_TRACKER)
        foreach(EXAMPLE distance_calibration)
            add_executable(${EXAMPLE} examples/c/${EXAMPLE}.c)
            target_link_libraries(${EXAMPLE} psmoveapi psmoveapi_tracker)
        endforeach()
    endif()
endif()
```

I guess I should add `-DBUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL` and `-shared` options somewhere. But where exactly? Or maybe I'm missing the point?

Comment: To make a dll you need `add_library(mydlltarget SHARED mysourcefiles)` not `add_executable(myexetarget mysourcefiles)`

Comment: Wow, that would be the only change here? Quite powerful ;)

Comment: You probably need to change the headers for the classes you want to export. I am not familiar with mingw dlls so I can't help with that.

Comment: Hmm. Looks the same as Visual Studio: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll see the part about `EXAMPLE_DLL`.

Comment: Yes, indeed :) Can you make an answer from your comments? I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a dll you need `add_library(mydlltarget SHARED mysourcefiles)` instead of `add_executable(myexetarget mysourcefiles)`

Also to make a dll from code that was an executable you will at minimum have to modify your headers to export the classes/functions that you want exported. From the documentation for [building a dll with mingw](http://%20mingw.org/wiki/sampledll) it appears that the process is similar to Visual Studio. Where you have a header define a macro that translates to `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the dll and `__declspec(dllimport)` when using the dll.

A sample of the export header looks like this:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL
#define EXAMPLE_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXAMPLE_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Then the modification for your class is like this:

```
class EXAMPLE_DLL MyClass
{
public:
        MyClass() {};
        virtual ~MyClass() {};
        void func(void);
};
```

Then you need to define `BUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL` when building the dll. You can do that in CMake with an `add_definitions(-DBUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL)`

Also CMake provides support for generating the export header with `GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER`

[Doc for GenerateExportHeader](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GenerateExportHeader.html)